Can two consecutive spokes be connected on the same side of the hub flange?
I've been trying to lace a 36 hole wheel by following the tutorials on youtube. After I finished, I realized that two consecutive spokes were on the same side of the hub flange. Wasn't it supposed to be the other way round?

Unless you are doing a pattern like 3-leading 3-trailing, the spoke heads always alternate. I don't think structually the hub minds, but it is better for the wheel to maintain rotational symmetry

A nice clear picture would help if you're struggling to track it down.  Sadly you've probably got a fair bit of un- and re-lacing ahead of you

BTW I prefer Sheldon's text and diagrams for wheelbuilding. I keep a greasy printout of the main parts. But then I'm never a fan of YouTube tutorials as reference material, especially when I need both hands for the task.

No, never, not even in any of the more offbeat patterns I've ever seen. You'll need to take a step back and think through what's needed to correct the mistake. There is at least one other spoke out of place.
